# How to add symbols to links in nav menu?

Tags: html, css

This is my homework question:

> Add the symbols to the links. To do that, use the background-image, background-
>   repeat, and background-position properties as shown in figure 5-11. The symbol is in
>   the images file, and it is named right.jpg. In this case, you don’t want to repeat the
>   image, and you want to position it in the middle vertically and about 95% from the
>   left.

My nav menu is supposed to look exactly like this:

[image]

But it ended up looking more like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<h2>Guest speakers</h2>
    <nav id="nav_list">
        <ul>
            <li> <h3> <a href="c06x_toobin.html">October<br>Jeffrey Toobin</a></h3></li>
                <li> <h3> <a href="#">November<br>Andrew Ross Sorkin</a></h3></li>
                <li> <h3> <a href="#">January<br>Amy Chua</a></h3></li>
                <li> <h3> <a href="c07x_toobin.html">February<br>Scott Sampson</a></h3></li>
        </ul>
                <h3> <a href="../index.html">Return to Home page</a></h3>
    </nav>

#nav_list ul { 
list-style: none;
margin-left: 1.25em;
margin-bottom: 1.5em;
background-image: url("images/right.jpg");
background-repeat:  no-repeat;
background-position: 95%;
}
#nav_list ul li { 
width: 200px;
margin-bottom: .5em;
border: 2px solid black; 
border-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px  #800000;
color:blue;
}
#nav_list ul li a {
display: block;
font-weight: bold;
color: blue;
text-decoration: none;
padding: .5em 0 .5em 1.5em; 
color: black;
}
```

How do I make it look exactly like the picture? I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: your background need to be on li, and not on ul. By the way, consider the :after pseudo-element instead of background-image :)

Comment: @iguypouf Wow, I feel so silly for not catching that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The background image should be on the `li` element, rather than the parent `ul`.

Also, you can position the background image via X and Y axis in the same property.

```
#nav_list ul { 
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 1.25em;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
#nav_list ul li { 
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  border: 2px solid black; 
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px  #800000;
  color:blue;
  background-image: url("images/right.jpg");
  background-repeat:  no-repeat;
  background-position: 95% 50%;
}
#nav_list ul li a {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .5em 0 .5em 1.5em; 
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a small "Arrow" image (for example 32x32 px) for the LI element. To be sure to see the arrow give the A element a transparent background. Also give the A some padding on the right side to prevent text will be over the arrow.

```
#nav_list ul { 
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 1.25em;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
#nav_list ul li { 
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  border: 2px solid black; 
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px  #800000;
  color:blue;
  background-image: url("images/right.jpg");
  background-repeat:  no-repeat;
  background-position: 170px 40px; /* from left & from top */
}
#nav_list ul li a {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .5em 3em .5em 1.5em; /* extra padding on right side */
  color: black;
  background: transparent; /* be sure to see the arrow image always */
}
#nav_list ul li a:hover {
  color: blue; /* mouse over text color */
}
```